# Run JS from Workspace in Chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have just started using Workspace in Chrome developer tools for development. Is there a way for me to run a piece of code from the editor. "Map to network resource" won't be of use here as the network resources are served after minifying and concatenating.

I am looking for "Run Snippet" button similar to what we have in "Snippets".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see an option ("Evaluate in console") to do this from the context menu. We have to select the snippet to be executed and right click > Evaluate in console. (Or, use shortcut Ctrl + Shift + E)

It would be better if we have a button similar to "Run Snippet". Logged a chromium feature request for this [Issue#339017](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=339017)

Comment: "Evaluate in console" doesn't give us the ability to debug the script in the sources panel like the old Snippets functionality did. So even if they added that shortcut it still wouldn't be a complete solution. I really hope that they bring back support for Snippets or at least give workspaces the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug into your code using 'Evaluate in console' by adding a 'debugger' statement to your code.

Not ideal but at least it works.

Comment: It's a good answer. Why is it voted down?